# PHP + jQuery: Apply datepicker to inputs with specific pattern

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I have a big form with at least 5 input date forms.

For example:

```
    <input type="text" id="nameClient" name="nameClient"/>
    <input type="text" id="nameRouterID" name="nameRouerID"/>
    <input type="text" id="dateInstallation" name="dateInstallation"/>
    <input type="text" id="dateConfiguration" name="dateConfiguration"/>
    <input type="text" id="dateConfirmationClient" name="dateConfirmationClient"/>
```

Well, i want to search the entire DOM for %date% word and apply datepicker jQuery plugin, avoiding to create this following lines for each element

```
    <script>
$( "#dateInstallation" ).datepicker();
$("#dateInstallation").datepicker("option", {dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
    });
    </script>';
```

I think it's possible to know with .find() function and "this" relative, but i'm not familiar. I think is something like this:

```
    $( "text" ).find( "%date%" ).datepicker();
```

And later:

```
    $(this).datepicker("option", {dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});
```

But i can't get it work I am not sure whether it is syntax problem or other

Comment: Could you perhaps add a class to each of the elements? `<input type="text" id="dateConfiguration" class="dateInput" name="dateConfiguration"/>`, and then `$('.dateInput').datepicker()`?

Comment: Oh, I have not think that, it's a good idea if it's not possible to search in the entire DOM. I have to mark it, but the rest is dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the attribute starts with selector to match ID's starting with `date`

```
 $('[id^="date"]').datepicker();
```

or to match any ID containing `date`, the attribute contains selector

```
 $('[id*="date"]').datepicker();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6S2Zx/)

Comment: Edit: It works! To apply the specific option, I add after $('[id^="date"]').datepicker("option", {dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true});